# code to fetch and return database string data based on dropdown box onchange event through .net controller class to form page using ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

C#,ASP.NET MVC,Ajax:-I have a form page where there is a drop down list showing customers name from database table customers.Based on the customer selection by passing customer id to database table I want to fetch his email id and contact number and display it in form read only text fields.My problem is controller code is not working.In other words i am not able to check whether id is reaching my controller function to fetch data and the query is executing or not.I am getting error function data on form page

My jquery code is as below

CustomerList1 is the id for drop down box

var cusKey to hold customer id

GetCustmrDetails is my controller function to fetch data based on id

```
$("#CustomerList1").change(function (event) {
        var cusKey = $("#CustomerList1").val();
        alert("customerKey:" + cusKey);
        $.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
              url: "/CustomerController/GetCustmrDetails/",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              data: JSON.stringify({ "id": cusKey }),
            success: function (data) {
                alert("available");
                $("#EMailAddress").val(data.EMailAddress);
                $('#Phone').val(data.Phone);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    });
```

My controller code is as below

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetCustmrDetails(int id)
    {

        List<CustomerModel> customer = new List<CustomerModel>();
        string query = string.Format("Select EMailAddress,Phone From 
        OC_Customer where CustomerKey="+id);
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    customer.Add(new CustomerModel{
                        EMailAddress = reader["EMailAddress"].ToString(),
                        Phone = reader["Phone"].ToString()
                    });
                }
            }
            return Json(customer, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
}
```

I want email id and contact number to display on form page(cshtml)

Comment: change only  url: "/CustomerController/GetCustmrDetails?id="+cusKey

Comment: url changed but still not working error function is executing

Comment: what error show in console

Comment: can anyone provide correct code to be placed in GetCustmrDetails function

Comment: this alert  alert("customerKey:" + cusKey); is occure or not

Comment: I am a new in asp.net mvc coding no error is showing in console.Is there any way to display id received in GetCustmrDetails function,like in java using System.out.println() we can print id on output console and can make sure id is reaching the function.Is there any code to display in asp.net mvc c#

Comment: alert is working well by displaying customerKey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please use this one

```
  $("#CustomerList1").change(function (event) {
    var cusKey = $(this).val();
    alert("customerKey:" + cusKey);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/Customer/GetCustmrDetails?id="+cusKey,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "{}",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("available");
            $("#EMailAddress").val(data[0].EMailAddress); 
            $('#Phone').val(data[0].Phone);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: still not fetching data from database table and not displaying the email and contact number in form

Comment: now hitting to method GetCustmrDetails or not, check by puting debugger

Comment: yes hitting to method.thanks,but how to put debugger?

Comment: now alert available is also working    but this code to display details not working $("#EMailAddress").val(data.EMailAddress);
 $('#Phone').val(data.Phone);

Comment: in methode GetCustmrDetails return Json(customer, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); replace with   var jsonResult = Json(customer, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
            return jsonResult;

Comment: i am getting returned data as [Object Object]

Comment: i got the code to display in correct format it's $("#EMailAddress").val(data[0].EMailAddress);
 $('#Phone').val(data[0].Phone);